# regex and mapping issue

Tags: ruby, regex, dictionary

I'm trying to write the Caesar cipher but am stuck trying to solve an issue with a regex used within a mapping loop. My code is:

```
class Cipher 

  attr_reader :string
  attr_reader :factor

  def initialize(string, factor)
    @string = string
    @factor = factor
  end

  def factored_ascii
    @string.chars.map do |letter|
      value = letter.ord + (@factor % 26)

      if letter =~ /[a-z]/ && value > 122
        value = (value % 122) + 96

      elsif letter =~ /[A-Z]/ && value > 90
        value = (value % 90) + 64

      elsif letter =~ /[^A-Za-z]/
        value = letter.ord
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

When calling `factored_ascii` on an object with the string argument "What a string", it only operates correctly on the first `W` character and on the space characters, setting the other elements as nils.

```
[66, nil, nil, nil, 32, nil, 32, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

I'm likely doing something rather daft. Can you help enlighten me and save me further hours trying to solve this one?

Comment: I can't understand what you would like to have as a result, but I can explain why you get nils. Your problem is in if-statement: it does not have `else` block which catches all other cases. As a result your iteration returns nil for most of chars. Pay attention that last regexp `/[^A-Za-z]/` has `^` which means start of line!

Comment: @gotva `^` inside `[]` means negation not start

Comment: oh, you are right. But I think it does not change the situation. It looks like the most letters are not caught by conditions inside if-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` maps values to the value *returned by the block*. Unless you explicitly return a value, the return value of a block is the value of the last statement executed. In your case, that's the if statement. When none of an if's conditions are met, it returns `nil`.

For example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
x.map do |y|
  if y % 2 == 0
    y
  end
end
# [nil, 2, nil, 4]
```

See how all the values that don't match the condition get `nil`? To fix your code, just put `value` after the if statement, which ensures that it is always the return value.

Answer (score 1):

@Max has answered your question, but you may want to consider writing the method differently:

```
def factored_ascii
  @string.chars.map do |letter|
    value = letter.ord + (@factor % 26)
    case(letter)            
    when /[a-z]/ && value > 122
      (value % 122) + 96
    when /[A-Z]/ && value > 90
      (value % 90) + 64
    when /[^A-Za-z]/
      letter.ord
    else
      value
    end 
  end
end

@string = "aZr$"
@factor = 0
factored_ascii #=> [97, 90, 114, 36]
```

This works because the `case` statement uses `===` (here [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)) for comparisons (e.g., `when /[a-z]/` is equivalent to `letter =~ /[a-z]/`).